# Copy Current Application Configuration and paste them into another application configuration in logi options+

Tags: windows, mac, mouse, logitech-mouse, software-update

I want to Copy Current Application Configuration and paste them into another application configuration in logi options+.
For example configuring specific gestures for chrome browser. Now, I want to copy this configuration and paste in into another application configuration for example firefox. Now I have to go to every setting to change it to match chrome configuration mouse gesatures.

Comment: According to a reddit post comment: "[Yes this is possible. Go to the mouse UI in logi options +. 
Backup settings on one PC.
GO to the other device and restore](https://www.reddit.com/r/logitech/comments/qqqfd0/syncronizing_settings_across_multiple_computers/)". I don't have this software to confirm though.

Comment: So then the (short) answer is probably no.

Comment: I just want to transfer the application configuration in logi optoins to another application configuration in logi options.